Arcgis Pro crashes each time I open a python (ipython) jupyter notebook
I have Arcgis Pro, ENVI and Agisoft Metashape on my laptop, but I've UNinstalled ENVI in case that is causing a problem (tho the problem persist w or w/o ENVI installed). When I try to open a ipython notebook on my laptop, it immediately crashes and I get the message:

The exception unknown software exception (0x40000015) occurred in the application at location 0x00007FFA169ACF19.
Click OK to terminate the program

The same ipython notebook opens just fine on my desktop and old laptop. And I've uninstalled and re-installed Arcgis Pro and the same result. Any clues? Might Agisoft be causing this problem?

Without being shown what's in the notebook (particularly what's causing the crash), I'd be hard pressed to divine the root cause of the problem here
